# Elastic Search Mapping to prepare Time Series visualization in Kibana

Tags: python-2.7, elasticsearch, kibana

I am mapping this data against customized unique _id
http://localhost:9200/index/type/_bulk
Mapping => {"settings" : {"index" : {"number_of_shards" : 5}},
"mappings" : { “type" : { "properties" : { “abc" : { "type" : "keyword" },”timestamp" : { "type" : “date” , “format” : "yyyy-MM-dd:HH:MM},”def" : { "type" : "integer" },”ghi" : { "type" : "integer" },”jkl" : { "type" : "keyword" },”mno" : { "type" : "keyword" },”pqr" : { "type" : "keyword" }}}}}

Now I am sending parsed data every hour to elastic search so it updates if there is an updated field and can be visualized on kibana. Now I want to visualize an time series of my data on timestamp field so now after above mapping Kibana recognize that it is time filter field name and also I can see on the time series and the time it is reported now as I am sending data every hour to elastic search so say if a field is updated it will update that document. Now in the case of time series visualization it does the same like it updates this field and overwrites the data so on the time series graph I am seeing single with the updated time stamp and old time stamp is overwritten by this new one so it doesn’t prepares an time series visualization 
Thank You.

Comment: Impossible to assist without looking at your code

Comment: I have rephrased my question for better understanding and to get advise on how to resolve it